# IndexError: list index out of range, using indexing in for loop

Tags: python

```
#Check if each element in input list is at least as big as the one before it.
inputList = [9,10,11,12,13]
flag=0
j = 1
i = 0
for i in range(len(inputList)):
    if inputList[i] < inputList[j] :
        flag=0
    elif inputList[i] > inputList[j] :
        flag=1
    else:
        flag=1
        print("Unexpected Error!!")

    if j < len(inputList):
        j=j+1
    else:
        j=j

if flag == 1 :
    print("Condition Failed")
else:
    print("Condition Passed")
```

Im trying to access index of my list from the for loop but its giving me Index Error.

I tried manually printing the indexes and it worked but not the other way

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prac3.py", line 13, in <module>
    if inputList[i] < inputList[j] :
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Why is it an "unexpected error" when the numbers are equal? Also, the loop doesn't terminate when `flag=0`, so the result will be wrong if the next pair of numbers sets `flag=1`. The simplest way to solve this is to use a pairwise list, like this: `all(b > a for a, b in zip(x, x[1:]))` (where `x` is the input list).

Comment: can you give little pseudo code

Comment: I just gave a complete, one-line solution. It returns `False` if any number is less than the previous one. (NB: empty or one-element input lists will always evaluate `True`).

Comment: Can you explain that one liner

Comment: and can you tell any fix in my code

Comment: If you do `print(list(zip(x, x[1:])))`, you can see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

`j` is always 1 bigger than `i`, so when `i` is the index of the last element, `j` is out of range -- hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

So after some time on @ekhumoro 's answer i found out the way.

```
res = all(b > a for a, b in zip(x, x[1:]))
if res == true:
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
#Check if each element in input list is at least as big as the one before it.
inputList = [9,10,11,12,13]
flag=0
j = 1
i = 0
for i in range(len(inputList)):
    if inputList[i] < inputList[j] :
        flag=0
    elif inputList[i] > inputList[j] :
        flag=1
    else:
        flag=1
        print("Unexpected Error!!")
    j=j+1 if j < len(inputList) else j=j

if flag == 1 :
    print("Condition Failed")
else:
    print("Condition Passed")
```

I have changed only one line for avoiding the error. You know better logic to implement your own algorithm.
`j=j+1 if j < len(inputList) else j=j`